# How to use Vuetify color picker (v-color-picker) at HEX mode without opacity option

Tags: vuetify.js

So I've been trying to use [vuetify's color picker](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/color-pickers/) with `hexa mode` like this:

```
      <v-color-picker
        v-model="color"
        mode="hexa"
        hide-mode-switch
        class="mb-4"
      />
```

And I can't figure out how to disable the opacity slider, I want to be able to keep the color slider without the opacity one. So at the input the user sees the color like `#FF0000` (7 digits) and not `#FF0000FF` (9 digits).

The `hide-sliders` prop hide them both (color and opacity) and there is not a specific one to the opacity slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically I found out if I init my `v-model` value with a object containing only a `hex` prop, the color picker hides the opacity slider and the color value is displayed with the 7 digits:

```
mounted() {
  this.color = {
    hex: '#FFF',
  };
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem is old, but I hope this solution helps someone.

This request has not yet been answered by the vuetify team, however, you can follow the process here:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9590

When they don't answer, this solution worked for me.

```
watch: {
    color(value) {
      // temporary fix while there is no way to disable the alpha channel in the colorpicker component: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9590
      if (value.toString().match(/#[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}/)) {
        this.color = value.substr(0, 7);
      }
    }
}
```

`color` is the `v-model` of the `<v-color-picker-component>`